# Can't install back yum on Centos 8

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, centos8, dnf

Yesturday I made the upgrade of my Centos 7 VM to Centos 8 following this tutorial :
https://www.tecmint.com/upgrade-centos-7-to-centos-8/

In this tutorial there is a step about removimg YUM package manager :
dnf -y remove yum yum-metadata-parser
rm -Rf /etc/yum

And I am not able now to install it back. There is like a look in the dependencies needed :
[image]

I can't install python3-dnf and dnf-data either because of dependencies :
[image]

It's very strange because I already have some of those dependencies installed :
[image]

I am very blocked, I don't really know what to do.
May be I don't need YUM but I miss it ...
It possible it could be because I haven't installed the good package for my distribution ?
Thanks

Comment: dnf  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNF_(software) . ... CentOS 8 has two yum packages: yum-4.7.0, yum-utils-4.0.21 . .... You can check the dependencies  at http://rpm.pbone.net/ .

Answer (score 2):

That is because your python3-dnf and python2-dnf have different versions. You do not need python2-dnf (that comes from el7). Remove it.

Also please mind that CentOS 8 will EOL in less than a month. So you should do:

```
dnf swap centos-linux-repos centos-stream-repos
```

Comment: No Updates : When that time comes, in four weeks, you can e.g. "Migrate CentOS 8 to Rocky Linux 8" https://linuxiac.com/centos-to-rocky-linux-migration/

Comment: Thank you both for your answers.
I will remove the python2-dnf  package so.
I saw that dnf is now the official package manager, is that usefull to install back yum ?
@KnudLarsen : I think I will update to Centos STream 8 and then 9. But I wasn't aware of Rocky Linux, interesting project.

Comment: The two new / dnf based yum packages ` yum-4.7.0, yum-utils-4.0.21` should be installed.

Comment: Yum is just symlink to DNF nowadays.